# SQL 2005 user denied SELECT permission

Tags: sql-server-2005, permissions

A domain user (User1) belonging to the roles public, db_datareader, and db_datawriter on a particular database is getting the following message when he attempts to select from any tables on that database (including newly created test tables):

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'table1', database 'database1', schema 'dbo'.
```

This user works perfectly on several of other databases on the same server. It is not explicitly denied permissions at the database or the table level (that I can find at least).

I've tried (to no avail):

- Removing and remapping the user to the database
- Assigning the user to the db_owner role
- Specifically granting select privileges at the database and table levels

The only thing that has made a difference is setting the user to the sysadmin server role - but this is not viable for production.

How else can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely that the user is a member of a group that has permissions denied - denies take precedence over grants.

Run the following to see the permissions;

```
select object_name(major_id) as object,
 user_name(grantee_principal_id) as grantee,
 user_name(grantor_principal_id) as grantor,
 permission_name,
 state_desc
from sys.database_permissions
 where major_id = object_id('table1')
 and class = 1
```

Could it be you're using ownership chaining, and hitting [this issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/lcris/archive/2007/09/13/basic-sql-server-security-concepts-ownership-chaining-good-and-evil-schemas.aspx)?

Hope this helps

Comment: the above query is one reason i still like to use sp_helprotect

Comment: Your diagnosis was correct, but the query didn't actually show this. Possibly because it was a database-level setting and not table level?